# Pass Image url through intent to a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android and currently facing some difficulties.
I have an imageview in which I have loaded a url, I want to pass its url (image_url) via intent to the new activity when the user clicks on the image(imageview).
in sending activity (//log.d shows the correct image_url)

```
    ImageView my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image);
    my_image.setClickable(true);        
    my_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleImage.class);
            i.putExtra("image_url", image_url);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In the receiving activity:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.image);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    id= i.getStringExtra(image_url);
```

in the receiving activity I am not receiving the image url that I passed through the sending activity. I would really appreciated it if someone can help

Comment: Is the i.getStringExtra returning <null> ?

Comment: You don't need to call my_image.setClickable(true);  Your ImageView is clickable by default.

Comment: Where are you attributing a value to the image_url variable?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Thank you very much. Erad has posted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
id = i.getExtras().getString("image_url");
```

Passing data through intents is in the form `putExtra (String name, String value)` with

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, String value)
Parameters
name    = The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
value   = The String data value.
```

When you try to get the passed data, you can use `getStringExtra (String name)` where

```
public String getStringExtra (String name)
Parameters
name    = The name of the desired item.
```

So when you getExtras, you have to use the String `name` - not a variable. (For your case: `i.getStringExtra("image_url");` instead of `i.getStringExtra(image_url);`)

See [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: If this solution worked for you, please indicate that it is the answer and vote up.

Comment: I have indicated that it's the answer is just that I cannot vote up :( it requires 15 reputation and I am new with not even one reputation. Sorry for that and thank you so much for the help